# For loop does not iterate, does not output more than first task of data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm really confused as this script has worked fine for several months and then today I noticed it was no longer working.

It is built using Google Scripts which uses Javascript, I can only log data using `Logger.log` so it's a little different to most Javascript but it works mainly the same.

I have found the area where the problem occurs. My `for` loop does not iterate through the array.

```
function checkGetAmount(currentDate,data){
  var arrayLength = data.length; // this outputs as 28 - is correct
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    // This is where the error occurs. If I try to output var I, it shows as "0" always

    if (data[i] == currentDate){
      i++;
      var amount = data[i];
      return amount;
    }else{
      return 'Not today';}
  }
}
```

I have tried to test why it is not crawling through all 29 elements of data. When I console logged var `i` it returned only `0`. I had expected it to output many console logs, starting with `0` then `1` etc up to `28`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Or how else I can iterate through my array `data`?

The purpose of the function is to run through each element of the array named `data` and check whether the var `currentDate` matches the data found in there. If it does, it should return the next array element.

Comment: can you include structure of data?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with your `for loop`. It might be here: `data.length`. Are you sure the `data` is arriving there with any content at all?

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes `data` is correct and stores the correct data as expected.

Comment: @AlexChar because of the way Google Scripts outputs stuff I can't show it as an array. But it's very simply just an array of 28 elements

Comment: This is happening because you return the value and the loop terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop does not iterate through the array, because you returning from function at the first interaction...
Your code should be (if I understood correctly):

```
function checkGetAmount(currentDate,data){
  for (var i = 0, toi = data.length; i < toi ; i++){
    if (data[i] == currentDate && data[i+1])
      return data[i+1];
  }
  return 'not found!';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. On the OP code, the two `return` statements are within an `if then else` block.

Comment: @MelanciaUK does not matter whithin or whithout `if/else` blocks, it's always return from the function. - [see](http://jsfiddle.net/x84sbqo5/)

Comment: If the first condition is met, it returns. If it isn't it also returns.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, and now I see what do you mean. Good spot.

Comment: @Andy is it weird for you to always return something from function?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, @KirillPisarev. Sometimes I write functions that don't return anything, they just process some data or something. Does that help?

Comment: @Andy Ok, void function... glad you know about it. But i don't really understood what did you tried to say in your first comment.

Comment: It was a response to MelanciaUK to explain why the loop wasn't working. If the condition is met the function will return. Also, if the condition isn't met it will return. The loop won't progress any further than zero, which is what you clarified in your answer.

Comment: ahh, i thought that you has fixed an error in my answer :)